# Undefined control sequence undetectable

Tags: math-mode, errors

I came across the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.206 ...quad a_k > \displaystyle\sum_{{\substrack
                                              {j=1 \\ j \neq k}}}^N\disp...
```

Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Read the FAQ entry [How do I ask questions here?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for guidance on voting and accepting answers.

Comment: It would be helpful if, in your posting, you only included the error message and left out the (at this point) meaningless LaTeX warnings.

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for the command `\substack` *not* `\substrack`.

Comment: Thak's for everyone and specially for Werner. After correction, I still have this error message:                      ! Undefined control sequence.
     l.206 ...\quad a_k > \displaystyle\sum_{{\substack
                  {j=1 \\ j \neq  k}}}^N\disp..

Comment: @Labaïr If you have an error message, why not edit the question showing what you did *and* the error message?

Comment: Now i have this message:                                        ! LaTeX Error: Environment remarques undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.396 \begin{remarques}

Comment: @Labaïr: The `remarques` environment is not defined. But this could be a host of things. For example, if it should be a "theorem" or a regular environment. You need to post more information.

Answer (score 8):

`\substack` is defined in the amsmath package, you need to load that package (or one of the ams classes that includes it)

Comment: Now I have this message:! LaTeX Error: Environment remarques undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.396 \begin{remarques}

Comment: so clearly you need to load whatever package defines that. i have never used it but http://lmgtfy.com/?q=latex+remarques  shows some hits

Comment: I write \newenvironment{remark}[1][\textbf{Remarques:}]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}} with the package ntheorem

Comment: I'm really surprised that after you are able to ignore the crowd of people who ask you to be fair and accept the answers to your questions. To your issue: Your environment is obviously named `remark` and not `remarque`.

Comment: I would like to extend my apologies to all people  in this post.

Comment: the newenvironment command that you show is defining a remark environment not a remarques environment (also it's using low level list enviromnent formatting not the ntheorem package) as you will by now have seen, it's rather hard to help if you don't provide a working example. If you only show code fragments and the errors are in parts of code not shown, then it leaves everyone guessing.

Comment: Thanks to all your  thoughts, I've been able to overcome all the errors that  were in the  document.